# Reading a file, how to pick only the lines starting with an integer?

Tags: python

I have a long text file few lines start with integer value i..e 2019, etc, and a few start with non-integer i.e. KP, AB, XY. I want to pick the first integer row and concat it with the non-integer rows and save it in a text file. Then, take the second integer row and concat with followed non-integer rows and save in the same text file, and so on.
The sample data file is like this.

''''

```
2019    15  3   13  57  22.3    34  73.71   0   2.2
AT  EP  357 36.36                       
ST  ES  358 17.22                       
ATT T   357 53.26                       
UO  ES  358 19.3                        
2019    11  4   7   18  58  33.17   70  1.1 2.3
PDA EP  743 8.6                     
TTY ES  743 23.73                       
NIL EP  743 12.75                       
2019    10  4   11  19  4.6 33.16   73.71   0   2.5
CET IP  1119    59.6                        
CET EP  1119    37.12                       
TU  ES  1119    59.36                       
THW EP  1119    37                      
2019    10  6   5   25  57.2    33.14   73.65   3.1 3.1
CET ES  526 50.28                       
CET EP  526 28
```

...

here we need to concat the first set of interger and non-integer rows i.e.

```
    2019    15  3   13  57  22.3    34  73.71   0   2.2
    AT  EP  357 36.36                       
    ST  ES  358 17.22                       
    ATT T   357 53.26                       
    UO  ES  358 19.3
```

In the second case, we concat the set subset, and so one.

```
2019    11  4   7   18  58  33.17   70  1.1 2.3
PDA EP  743 8.6                     
TTY ES  743 23.73                       
NIL EP  743 12.75
```

Comment: Read word by word, not line by line. and then try to cast it to int. Make sure you wrap it on a try except clause

Comment: There is no `x` so why would you expect `print(x)` to "work" in any way? Please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, "it's not working" is not a good description.

Comment: Your example suggests we could get away with simply `if line.startswith('2019'):` or `line.startswith('20')`. But you say *"starting with any integer value"*, can we assume it's a 4-digit year? 20xx? or 19xx? or 18xx? Please edit your example to be clearer.

Comment: a) In your code the `if i==2019:`condition must be followed by a colon ':'. b) you need to indent the `print(x)`, resumably you meant it to be the clause of the if-statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is giving you numbers `0, 1, 2, ...` i.e., line number minus 1. Unless you have more than 2019 lines, that `if` won't evaluate to `True`..

Instead you can look at the line instead, which is in the `line` variable. It's a string in each turn, so you can look at the very first character of it and see [if it is a digit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
for line in f:
    if line[0].isdigit():
        print(line)
```

---

To write the integer-starting lines and others to 2 separate files, open 2 such file, then write with `print` according to the `if`:

```
integers_file = open("integers.txt", "w")
others_file = open("others.txt", "w")

for line in f:
    if line[0].isdigit():
        print(line, file=integers_file, end="")
    else:
        print(line, file=others_file, end="")

integers_file.close()
others_file.close()
```

where we passed `end=""` to `print` to avoid the extra new line, as one newline comes from the read file's lines.

Comment: Thanks this solves my major problem. I am also trying to save it as a text file for digit and one for non-digit:  f = open("Arrivals_data.txt")
for line in f:
    if line[0].isdigit():
        print(line)
file = open('uuu.txt', 'w')
file.write(line)
file.close()

Comment: @Adnan Edited the answer. You can open 2 files beforehand and write depending on `if`.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("data.txt")

for line in f:
    try:
        x = int(line.split(" ")[0])  # can determine integer otherwise in except block
        print(x)
    except:
        continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
import re
for line in f.readlines():
    if re.match("^2019", line): print("Yeah!")
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help if you want to integer comparisons:

```
import re

f = open("data.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
p = re.compile('^([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]).*')
for line in lines:
    result = p.match(line)
    if result:
        year = int(result.group(1))
        if year == 2019:
            print(line)
```

Comment: On the line `if result!= None:`. Never use != to compare to None, use `is None` or `is not None`. But in general you don't need that, it's Pythonic to just do `if result:` on your match object.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("data.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if (line.split(' ')[0]).isdigit():
            print(line)
```